# Visual Studio 2010 Debug DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

On my other computer, I can build a C++ dll.
Attach the visual studio debugger to a process.
Set a breakpoint, and then inject the dll into the process to step through it and make live changes.

That was on Windows 7 x32/x86 bit.

I am currently on Windows 7 x64 bit using the exact same project, dll, target process, and dll loader.

However, the break point never triggers.
It doesn't even show that it detected the module in the console.

How can I debug my dlls with Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 x64 bit?

Comment: Make sure you don't have a bitness problem. You can't inject a 32 bits DLL in a 64 bits process. How do you inject? Does Process Explorer show the DLL loaded in the target process?

Comment: You can also use the `Modules` window (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) and make sure that your specific module is loaded. There are no specific problems regarding debugging of x64 processes.

Comment: Another hint: what does the tooltip say when you point your mouse on the breakpoint?